# String from Object Python

Tags: python, xml, string, object, tkinter

I am working on a project that uses XML to create a Tkinter GUI and need to know how to convert an object name to a string.  For example:

```
# In the actual program, the value of widget variables is set by the values of XML attributes

label_name = "mylabel"

root = Tk()

exec(label_name+" = Label("+str(root)+", text='Hello World')")
```

Using `str(root)` does not work. What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the string `root`:

```
exec(label_name + " = Label(root, text='Hello World')")
```

Demo:

```
In [31]: root = tkinter.Tk()
In [32]: from tkinter import Label
In [33]: exec("label_name = Label(root, text='Hello World')")
In [34]: print(label_name.grid_size())
(0, 0)
```

Comment: This would be great... but root isn't the only possibility for a master argument... for example I might be placing it inside a Frame instead of the root

Comment: @CaptainCucumber, makes no difference just put the string in there and exec will take care of the rest